# Create own styles in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Every time I try to customize the style of a view I have the same problem.
What parameters can I change; and how to override the system defaults? For example:

- How to change the highlighted color of a element of a `ListView` when clicked
- How to change the default `frame` of a `DialogFragment`? I mean the frame that is removed with the Style `DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME`.

Where can I check what are the values I should play with for achieve my custom layouts?

Thanks

Comment: @What have you tried so far that isn't working? Can you show some code?

Comment: I really didn't try anything. Because I imagine that changing the highlighted is change an attribute in a Style or in the ListView xml but I have no idea of what to change :D

Answer (score 0):

Well you can change the look by creating a new xml file in the drawable folder but dont make a layout xml jus pick andrid xml from the wizard and it will give u a list of components you can modify including colour.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="1dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="25dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_purple" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:top="1dp" android:left="400dp" android:right="2dp"   android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_purple" />

        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="1dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="400dp"              android:bottom="1dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_purple" />

        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

then you can just change whats required!
But provider some code and i will be able to answer better..